# How much resistance is needed in inferno for a melee class?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk, diablo-iii-barbarian

I got some lightning resist, and with the Monk's [One With Everything](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/one-with-everything) passive, that puts all my resists at 200%, but I still think that is too low.

How much resistance does a melee class need to be effective in Inferno?

Comment: As a sidenote, 200 is not 200%; resistances work like armor now.  The tooltip will tell you how much elemental resist you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been various debates over the effectiveness of stacking resist. I'd say that it's extremely helpful, but make sure you maintain a decent amount of health and damage. Focus on one resist and take the passive if you want to build this way. Around act II or III, you can reach at least 300 resist (at least 50% resist).

While there may be several viable stat builds, resist is definitely one of the most effective. Why? At the higher difficulties, the only true threats are elite packs and champions that use Arcane Enchant, Molten, Fire Chain, as well as several other damaging skills. Resist helps to counter the majority of these.

Comment: Now I have heard that a barb with 1k all resist and 70k life dies with 2 hits =/
Hope I can get higher resist values than the barb

Comment: Do note that Armor is applied to all damage, so it helps against these elites as well (elemental resist is considered as well, and "physical" is an element).

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect. If you are in A3 and only have 300 resist all, you will get demolished no matter what you do. I personally have around 1200 all resist, 55k life and 11k armor, and I still have a hard time against certain monster combinations (although I can clear most of A3 and A4 completely without problems). Also, the elementary resistances are in no way the primary things you're going for with stacking AR. Instead, physical resistance is what is going to make you survive the most, since it stacks on top of armor.

Answer (score 2):

Playing lvl 60 barb with around 700 all resist, meaning (according to the ingame inventory tooltip) 68~71% damage reducing, 9k def, 47k hp, 8,9k dps 231% crit amp. and doing inferno act I easily as hell. Tanking (mean standing in arcane / plague / fire spells damage area 50% of the time) any elite pack without any problem, taking just the "bomb time" (Berserk + Inferno) to kill those. Already soloe'd butcher in around 3min without poting. The thing IS, when it comes to act II, my friend, the whole scene changes. The damage is much higher and reading some forums, the resistance starts to make some effect at around 900all.

Comment: Is that number for resistance **after** the 50% bonus for War Cry runed with Impunity, or is that the unbuffed number?

Comment: Please post your gear for this.

Comment: Head: 114str 81vit 3% repel socket w/ 13%+life
Shoulder: 169str +66 all resist

Comment: Amulet: 91int 203vit +68 all resist
Chest: 144vit +36arcane resist 16%mf 2sockets w/ +38vit ea.
Gloves: +122str +50vit +49int +27poison res. +21%crit dmg. +4,5% crit chance
Fist: +145str +39fire res. +39 all resist
Ring 1:+45str +127vit +18poison res. +25%crit dmg.
Ring 2:12-25dmg +34str +47vit +19poison res. +25%crit dmg.
Belt: +126str +80vit +27phys. res. +54all resist

Comment: Legs: +105vit +37arcane res. +44all resist 2 sockets w/ +38vit ea.
Feets: +25str +82vit +62int +60all resist
Weap: 613,5dps +243str +63vit 1 socket w/ +60%crit dmg.
Shield: +44all resist -12%cc effect time

Answer (score 1):

I have almost no resistance, and on my monk, I do ok soloing in Inferno, and I estimate I can kill about a third of elites without dying, half with maybe 1-6 deaths, and I abandon about a sixth of the packs.

Run speed, dodge (which is also damage), and crowd control skills alone are enough to do extremely well.

I use *all* of my crowd control skills, Mantra of Evason with run speed, run speed boots, run speed passive, and Deadly Reach as my only damage dealer.

None is *needed*.

Note that this answer is about monks - I don't have a lvl 60 barb.

Comment: Why do you say dodge is also damage? And running with Deadly Reach you run like you were ranged?

Comment: Yes, if the elites aren't too fast, I use Deadly Reach like a ranged attack.  Otherwise, i only deal damage when either the enemy is blinded or feared, or I'm invincible, which can be as high as %30-35 of the time.

Comment: Dodge is based on Dexterity, and Dexterity is a huge component of damage.  That's all I mean.  Having a high DPS weapon is also really important, but I guess I didn't actually say that :/

Comment: The primary problem with this type of build is the sheer amount of elites that you won't be able to kill. It's not that you would be less effective, you wouldn't be able to kill them at all. Run speed is nice, but there are so many skills (jailer, vortex, nightmare, waller) that easily counter run speed.

Comment: if you have it pumped all the way, you can actually get out of range pretty easily after you blind or fear, and wait until your Serenity is off cooldown.  It doesn't work nearly as well indoors, for exactly the problems you mention.  I think a resistances build is likely better once you have the gear, but I still only abandon maybe one in six elites.

Answer (score 1):

All you need for a Monk really is 600-700 resist all. My monk is lvl 60 with 620 all resist. Don't base yourself on LOH dps and be a tank (boring and slow) - I have 2.20 speed with 33kdps with Deadly Reach. I am at 50K+ dps with armor at 9k and 47k+ HP.

I clear Act 3-4 pretty fast =). To tell you the truth I feel no difference between Act 1 and 3/4.

Speed for monk is still the keys for soloing. =)

Comment: pretty decent stats, but note that this topic was before the inferno nerf patch

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any resistances until you reach Act 2 Inferno.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently a lvl 54 monk with 426 resist all and I'm doing just fine in Hell. I got high DPS 2x 1-h weapons with poison res and stacking dex. I'm using nothing but dex and poison res stacking on everything (and whatever other things are on the items themselves like int, which also increases res) but using the passive skill that makes it where all my resistances are what my highest resistance is. So far I'm having no problems.

I didn't think about this until I was level 50 and kept dying in Hell like every 5 seconds fighting the elites. So far, so good. Let's see how this goes once I get to lvl 60 and have a lot more res and dex stacked up.